# change array structure best on special key in php

Tags: php, arrays

I need to do something with array and cannot figure out how.
I have this array:

```
$arr = array(
       "0" => array("var_id" => 11, "var_name" => 'london', "var_price" => 250),
       "1" => array("var_id" => 22, "var_name" => 'moscow', "var_price" => 320),
       "2" => array("var_id" => 33, "var_name" => 'chicago', "var_price" => 99),
       "3" => array("var_id" => 11, "var_name" => 'london', "var_price" => 140),
       "4" => array("var_id" => 44, "var_name" => 'amsterdam', "var_price" => 555),
       "5" => array("var_id" => 33, "var_name" => 'chicago', "var_price" => 663),
       "6" => array("var_id" => 33, "var_name" => 'chicago', "var_price" => 777)
    );
```

i want to be able to change array structure in this example i need new array with only 4 main cities: london,moscow,chicago,amsterdam the unique key will be var_id and inside them the array of prices like this:

```
$arr_new = array(
   "0" => array("var_id" => 11, "var_name" => 'london', "var_price" => array("0" => 250,"1" => 140)),
   "1" => array("var_id" => 22, "var_name" => 'moscow', "var_price" => array("0" => 320)),
   "2" => array("var_id" => 33, "var_name" => 'chicago', "var_price" => array("0" => 99,"1" => 663,"2" => 777)),
   "3" => array("var_id" => 44, "var_name" => 'amsterdam', "var_price" => array("0" => 555))
);
```

if there is any php class or function that can do it (i prefer class).
this is a good screenshot i made:

[my arrays dbug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBTJx.jpg)

Comment: No, there isn't something premade. But you can easily achieve this yourself with a loop.

Comment: look into array_sort

Comment: Something like this https://3v4l.org/5Q5Qg

Comment: Hello Charlotte Dunois thank you very much, this is just what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `foreach` loop like this:

```
$array = array(
   "0" => array("var_id" => 11, "var_name" => 'london', "var_price" => 250),
   "1" => array("var_id" => 22, "var_name" => 'moscow', "var_price" => 320),
   "2" => array("var_id" => 33, "var_name" => 'chicago', "var_price" => 99),
   "3" => array("var_id" => 11, "var_name" => 'london', "var_price" => 140),
   "4" => array("var_id" => 44, "var_name" => 'amsterdam', "var_price" => 555),
   "5" => array("var_id" => 33, "var_name" => 'chicago', "var_price" => 663),
   "6" => array("var_id" => 33, "var_name" => 'chicago', "var_price" => 777)
);

$final_arr = [];

foreach ($array as $key => $arr) {
    $final_arr[$arr['var_name']]['var_name'] = $arr['var_name'];
    $final_arr[$arr['var_name']]['var_id'] = $arr['var_id'];
    $final_arr[$arr['var_name']]['var_price'][] = $arr['var_price'];
}

var_dump(array_values($final_arr));
```

The expected output would be like this:

```
array:4 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "var_id" => 11
    "var_price" => array:2 [
      0 => 250
      1 => 140
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "var_id" => 22
    "var_price" => array:1 [
      0 => 320
    ]
  ]
  2 => array:2 [
    "var_id" => 33
    "var_price" => array:3 [
      0 => 99
      1 => 663
      2 => 777
    ]
  ]
  3 => array:2 [
    "var_id" => 44
    "var_price" => array:1 [
      0 => 555
    ]
  ]
]
```

- [See code in action](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8a738742706198d34c903d08501407a0b6184731)
- [See it in different PHP Versions](https://3v4l.org/oBKu8)

Comment: _Note:_ Implicitly creating arrays like the last line will fail in PHP 7.1, where you explicitly need to set it as an array before you can push elements to it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - It will not fail, you can see code in action link from the answer and select php version 7.1 there and execute the code!

Comment: Ah, yeah. It might only be when you do it on an empty string it throws a fatal error, instead if converting it to an array, as it use to.

Comment: @bytech - If you find this answer correct and helpful then accept & upvote this answer as it motivates me to give answers to other questions like this and helps others to quickly find the correct answer!

Comment: Hello Saumya Rastogi and thank you very much.
its working but how its know to do it by key "var_id"?

Comment: @bytech - Just replace array key `var_name` to `var_id`, like this - `$final_arr[$arr['var_name']]` to `$final_arr[$arr['var_id']]`. This would work like a charm.